# Javascript to show anchor tag title attribute in modal onclick

Tags: javascript, php, css

Just wondering if you can point me in the right direction here. I have this PHP code and want to be able to use onclick on dynamically created links to display the link's title in a modal window with close option. Sort of like a tooltip. Don't want to use the native browser tooltip. Am assuming Javascript would be best? Any pointers would be very much appreciated.

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{ ?> 
<a style="font-size:16px;" ID="<? echo $row['ID'] ?>" title="<? 
echo  $row ['title']  ?> 
by
<? echo $row ['author'] ?>"><span title=""><? echo $row ['first_line'] ?>
</span></a>

<?
echo "&nbsp"; 
if ($count >= 6) 
{ 
echo '<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'; 
$count = 0; 
} else { 
$count++; } 

}
```

Comment: You're on the right path. Use jQuery's .on() to see when the dynamic anchor tag is clicked. Then grab the val() of the title attribute of $this as a variable. Then dump that variable inside the modal wherever you want it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use bootstrap or another css/js framework to show modal
and customize modal show method like below:

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/saeedsalehi/1aeur58f/665/`
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to the  links (say, 'alertTitle'). Then, here's the JS that could help you, if I get the question right:

```
var els = document.getElementsByClassName('alertTitle');
// Add event listener to each
for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++){
  els[i].onclick = function(){
  window.alert(this.title); // You could do anything with this.title
}
```

Here's the working example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vt3r89s3/)

Answer (score -1):

Use the event listener `$('a').on()`:

```js
var modal = $('#my-modal');

$('a').on('click', function() {
  var title = $(this).attr('title');
  modal.find('.modal-title').text(title);
  $('#my-modal').modal('show');
});
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<a href="#1" id="1" title="Title 1">Link 1</a><br/>
<a href="#2" id="2" title="Title 2">Link 2</a><br/>
<a href="#3" id="3" title="Title 3">Link 3</a><br/>

<div id="my-modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nikita_r/zpjeLL56/)